# Can't Call Method in DialogFragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity. In this Activity, I set Fragment B. Then in Fragment B, I call DialogFragment C. Now I want to call method in DialogFragment **KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment** , but the method is not getting called

this is how I Call DialogFragment **KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment** in Fragment B

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment manageFaq = new KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment();
        manageFaq.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        manageFaq.setCancelable(false);
        manageFaq.setDialogTitle("Konfirmasi Pembayaran Pendaftaran Peserta");
        manageFaq.show(fragmentManager, "Konfirmasi");
        manageFaq.setData(detailJadwal);
```

Now I Call method in DialogFragment From My ParentActivity

```
KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment curFrag = (KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Konfirmasi");
            if(curFrag!=null &&  curFrag.getDialog()!=null
                    && curFrag.getDialog().isShowing()) {
                // call method
            } else {
                // DialogFragment not detect 
            }
```

The Problem : curFrag is null, So how to solve it ?

Comment: Please check this line:FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager(); Why don't you use getFragmentManager()?

Comment: Because KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment  is called from another fragment (Fragment B)

Comment: You can call getFragmentManager() in Fragment B

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment curFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Konfirmasi");
        if (curFrag != null) {
            FragmentTransaction removeTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            removeTransaction.remove(prev);
            removeTransaction.commit();
        }

        // Create and show the dialog Fragment.
        if(curFrag ==null){
            curFrag = new KonfirmasiPembayaranPesertaFragment ();
        }
        curFrag.show(getFragmentManager(),"Konfirmasi");
    }
```